# Does speed of select query depends on number of rows and columns returned?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database table with 1000 records.

I have two choices now to display them to my users.

Choice 1) **Select all at once** and display.

Choice 2) Load more : Select 20 rows at the beginning using **limit** and load next 20 when user scrolls down

Now my question is which is the better choice? 
Does second choice improve the performance?
**Does query speed depends on the number of rows it has to return**?

Of course I have indexed the required columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both options are equally slow *for the database*.

Let's explain a bit *why*.

> Choice 1) Select all at once and display.

This is going to take up some time to send through network, and most likely a while before browser parses the data. 1000 records isn't really that huge of a number so it's most likely going to be rather quick - however, that rule won't hold up if your records grow with time.

> Choice 2) Load more : Select 20 rows at the beginning using limit and load next 20 when user scrolls down

I assume here that you are going to use `LIMIT 20 OFFSET X` - what MySQL will do is find all the records satisfying the condition, buffer it, find 20 records and discard X records. It basically does the same work as your choice 1. Usually, to help MySQL a bit we use indexes and some trickery to help it reduce the data set it has to go through - I won't go into this into detail.

Final part is - and this is to remember for an eternity when it comes to performance - to make something work *fast* means to make it work **less**. If you return 20 rows of data instead of 10, it means you did twice the work essentially.

The other part when it comes to performance is to find satisfying trade-offs. For example, 10 or 20 rows is really negligible. even 1000 rows isn't that much of a data if you take into consideration network bandwidth available these days. What we, developers, have to do is find the least work for our server and for our client (browser in most cases). How you find it and if you find it depends on your judgement and choices while constructing the application and the underlying infrastructure.

However, to get back at the original question - sending 1000 rows will be slower in general because network will have to send more data, and user will have to receive more data at once. Sending 10 or 20 at a time is slow for the database, but rather quick and easy for network / browser. It's up to you what you decide to go for.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it would be better to show all the rows. In general, a good rule to follow is to cache a large amount of data on the server, and pull from that list. Then when that list is close to being used up, asynchronously pull more from the database in case the user keeps going forward.

The reason for this is that one of the heaviest parts of making a query against the database is actually connecting to the database. This is one of the reasons why joins in code are bad compared to joins in the sql query (another reason being that databases are optimized for data aggregation while code is optimized for business logic).

Comment: Thank you. Does query execution speed depends on number of rows it returned? I mean does select * from table limit 0,10 > select * from table limit 0,20

Comment: Yes, but marginally so. If you are copying data directly into an object in code, you should be able to translate 30,000 objects in under 10 seconds (and probably faster).